# PHP MYSQL connect error

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, connection-string

I need a little help,I'm new in php mysql, and i dont know why does my script not insert the row in database.
I start apache and mysql in xammp and I create the database(users) and the table(users). 
Maybe I'm not seeing something, could use a little help.

Config.inc.php

```
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbDatabase = "test";
$dbHost = "localhost";

$dbConn = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);

if($dbConn){
  mysql_select_db($dbDatabase);  
  print ("Succsess");
}
else {
    die("<strong>ERROR</strong>Could Not connect to Database");
}


?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");

print ("<br>Inserting rows ...");
$password = "test";
mysql_query("ISERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('myemail@gmail.com','" . sha1($password)  .  "' , 'Flamur')");
echo "<br>Done";
?>
```

I also use sha1 to encrypt my password :P .
Thnx for helping :)

Comment: What's the actual error from the database?  Use `mysql_error()` to determine the database's response.  It's probably trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: forgot to mention: ID(Primary, type serial), email, password and name are the columns (type varchar[255]).

Comment: @David it does not insert the row.

Comment: if you are new then try using mysqli or PDO instead of mysql since its deprecated.

Comment: i got the answer "INSERT" not ISERT , Shame

Comment: @Flamur: The point is, "it does not insert the row" isn't the error.  The database is *telling* you the error, which is a syntax problem with your code.  It's telling you *exactly* where in the query the error is.  You just need to pay attention to the database's response.  `mysql_error()` would be used in this case to determine that error.  Don't ignore error messages, read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got mistake in:

```
mysql_query("ISERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('myemail@gmail.com','" . sha1($password)  .  "' , 'Flamur')");
```

You must use `INSERT` no `ISERT` so try to replace your line with this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('myemail@gmail.com','" . sha1($password)  .  "' , 'Flamur')");
```

Comment: Thnx pes502 , what a mistake lol

Answer (score 1):

It is `INSERT` not `ISERT` on your query.

```
mysql_query("ISERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('myem
            ^^^^^
```

Also, This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to PreparedStatements is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Since you are in the starting phase , I suggest you go through [**Prepared Statements**](http://in3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: I appreciate that much, THNX